# Owin in MVC Web API giving CancelationToken exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, cancellation-token

**Environment**: .NET 4.6.1, ASP.NET MVC 2, Microsoft.Owin

**Application Situation**

- Owin configured for OAuth based authentication (own db).
- Authorize attribute *not* added yet. Was next step

**Code base**

*Startup*

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        OAuthConfig oAuthConfig = new OAuthConfig(app, AppConfiguration);
        oAuthConfig.ConfigureOAuthTokenGeneration();
        oAuthConfig.ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption();

        WebApiConfig.Register(AppConfiguration);
        app.UseWebApi(AppConfiguration);

        // No further configuration is now allowed. 
        AppConfiguration.EnsureInitialized();
    }
```

*OAuthConfig*

```
    public OAuthConfig(IAppBuilder app, HttpConfiguration HttpConfiguration)
    {
        this.app = app;
        if (OAuthConfig.HttpConfiguration == null)
            OAuthConfig.HttpConfiguration = HttpConfiguration;

        this.app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
        {
            try
            {
                await next();
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                // Eat this exception
            }
        });
    }

    public void ConfigureOAuthTokenGeneration()
    {
        var userStore = HttpConfiguration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IUserStore<ExtendedUser, string>)) as IUserStore<ExtendedUser, string>;
        UserService.UserStore = userStore;
        this.app.CreatePerOwinContext<UserService>(UserService.Create);
        this.app.CreatePerOwinContext<SignInService>(SignInService.Create);

        var issuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:IssuerServer"];
        var tokenEndpoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:OwinTokenEndpoint"];    // "/oauth/token"
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            ////For Dev enviroment only (on production should be AllowInsecureHttp = false)
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new Microsoft.Owin.PathString(tokenEndpoint),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = new CustomOAuthProvider(),
            AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat(issuer)
        };

        // OAuth 2.0 Bearer Access Token Generation
        this.app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthServerOptions);
    }

    public void ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption()  {
        string audienceId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceId"];
        var issuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:IssuerServer"]; // Should have the Url of the auth server http://localhost:53025/";
        byte[] audienceSecret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceSecret"]);
        this.app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
            new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                AllowedAudiences = new[] { audienceId },
                IssuerSecurityKeyProviders = new IIssuerSecurityKeyProvider[]
                {
                    new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityKeyProvider(issuer, audienceSecret)
                }
            });
    }
```

*CancelledTaskHandler*

```
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        // Try to suppress response content when the cancellation token has fired; 
        //    ASP.NET will log to the Application event log if there's content in this case.
        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }

        return response;
    }
```

*WebApiConfig*

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
    // routes and other config
        // Handle CancellationToken which sometimes causes the app to hang due to orphaned responses
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new CancelledTaskMessageHandler());
     }
```

**Issue being faced**

- In development machines (local testing), no issues running the api and consuming that
- On deployment, there are errors in windows application log reporting as follows:

  ```
  Exception type: OperationCanceledException 
  Exception message: The operation was canceled.
  at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
  at System.Web.Http.Owin.HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.<BufferResponseContentAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
  ```

**Question**

- Not sure why Owin even kicks in when no authentication is requested,
  only the handlers have been set.
- Any impact on performance due to this?

**Attempts already made**

Eating out exception in Owin pipeline (within OAuthConfig's constructor)

```
        this.app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
        {
            try
            {
                await next();
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                // Eat this exception
            }
        });
```

Although we don't have Authorize enabled right now, but wondering if this can suggest some other problem with design which may lead to issues later on.

Any other specific artifact can be included, if required. 
Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code?  Specifically your startup.cs file, but also anything that could be called.  More than likely you are throwing an exception which is bubbling up in an asynchronous method.

Comment: @MichaelDotKnox the exception is coming from Owin pipeline, and why is it triggering in first place when there isn't any authorize requests ?

Comment: OWIN has nothing to do with authorization.   It is a pipeline that runs before your application (more complicated than that).   The fact that it is throwing an exception means that you are doing something with it which is why we need to see your code.   We can’t answer questions if we can’t see the problem.

Comment: @MichaelDotKnox added code for different classes under startup mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me start by giving you a very brief description of how OWIN works.  It is worth it for you to read more about it, but this is a good starting point.

Think of OWIN as a pipeline between the request and your application, which in this case is an MVC Web Api.  Each piece of the pipeline is called "middleware" and the request flows through this pipeline until it reaches your application.  When the request reaches the pipeline, the flow reverses and the data flows back through the pipeline.  So each piece of this pipeline (the "middleware") sees the data twice, when the data comes in to the application and when it leaves the application.  The middleware can look at or modify the request when it comes in, or look at or modify the response when it leaves your application, or both.

Each middleware component receives a dictionary containing various pieces of data about the request and response and a delegate that calls the next piece of the pipeline.

Now for your code:

Your application is WebApi, as defined by these lines:

```
app.UseWebApi(AppConfiguration);
```

You have two pieces of middleware that you initialize with these lines:

```
    var issuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:IssuerServer"];
    var tokenEndpoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:OwinTokenEndpoint"];    // "/oauth/token"
    OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
    {
        ////For Dev enviroment only (on production should be AllowInsecureHttp = false)
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        TokenEndpointPath = new Microsoft.Owin.PathString(tokenEndpoint),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
        Provider = new CustomOAuthProvider(),
        AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat(issuer)
    };

    // OAuth 2.0 Bearer Access Token Generation
    this.app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthServerOptions);
```

and then these lines:

```
    string audienceId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceId"];
    var issuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:IssuerServer"]; // Should have the Url of the auth server http://localhost:53025/";
    byte[] audienceSecret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceSecret"]);
    this.app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
        new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            AllowedAudiences = new[] { audienceId },
            IssuerSecurityKeyProviders = new IIssuerSecurityKeyProvider[]
            {
                new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityKeyProvider(issuer, audienceSecret)
            }
        });
```

This middleware will always run.  Doesn't matter if you have any attributes anywhere.

You said that the error does not occur on local development machines, which means that you most likely have a configuration issue.  You are passing settings into your middleware in the above referenced lines.

Based on that I would suspect that you have a problem with the `issuer` or `tokenEndpoint` variables or (more likely) the `audienceId` or `audienceSecret` variables.

Hope that helps.